# Justifying form elements to fill a div horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div>
    <label for="ctl00_cph_address">Address</label>
    <input name="ctl00$cph$address" type="text" id="ctl00_cph_address" class="required text">
    <a id="ctl00_cph_addCcContact">Add</a>
    <span id="ctl00_cph_addressrequiredValidator" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span id="ctl00_cph_addressValidator" style="display: none;"></span>
</div>
```

I would like the label to be fixed width and right aligned, and this is normally easy, but what is near impossible is to get the `addCcContact` anchor to right align to the right side of the containing div. I have achieved this with absolute positioning and floating, but surely, somehow, there is a way to use `text-align` to do this. Why is this so difficult?

Comment: Can you post the CSS you have so far? Maybe even use the `<>` button to make it a runnable jsFiddle-like snippet.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think there is a text-align that lets you right-align the last 'word' while left-aligning the rest, so float or position is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is if you set the `text-align` on the `<a>` it will correctly right-align the text *inside the `<a>` element*, but the `<a>` will still only take up the space it needs, and it will flow immediately after the input. On the other hand, if you set `text-align` on the containing `<div>`, then everything inside the `<div>` will shove over to the right.

So you need to either use something like floating or positioning, or decide what you want to occupy the intervening space - the `<input>`, or an invisible element, or the `<a>` itself. And then you can size the elements accordingly, using e.g. flexbox.

For example, to make the `<input>` fill the rest of the width:

```css
div {
  display:flex;
}
input {
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="ctl00_cph_address">Address</label>
    <input name="ctl00$cph$address" type="text" id="ctl00_cph_address" class="required text">
    <a id="ctl00_cph_addCcContact">Add</a>
    <span id="ctl00_cph_addressrequiredValidator" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span id="ctl00_cph_addressValidator" style="display: none;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is I want `<a>` to be it's minimum width, on the right, and the `input` to fill the remaining width between the label and the anchor.

Comment: @ProfK did this do what you wanted in the end?